# Django static image not loading for a CSS div background

Tags: html, css, django

I have a Django site, whose home page contains a `div` that has it's background image defined as:

```
.background-1
{
    {% load static %}
    background-image: url("{% static "personal/images/ind.jpeg" %}") ;
}
```

Now, as I do `./manage.py runserver` and open the localhost, the site runs properly, but the image is not shown in the background.

From what I know about Django, `url` must need a `url`. Thus the image should be loaded via : `{% url 'url-pattern-name' 'input' %}`, which would need a few modifications in the `views.py` and `urls.py` files.

Otherwise, I would need to remove this part from the CSS, and add a `src = {% static "pers...%}` to the `div` tag, directly into the html.

I just am not sure, if there is no other way to solve this problem. Specifically, with using the static call.

Comment: You don't want to serve `.css` from Django. Keep the `.jpeg` files relative to the `.css. file and use a relative path directly in the .css: `url("personal/images/ind.jpeg")`

Comment: For background image, you can directly add the image link, instead of static call.